# Generate random matrix

Tags: perl, random, matrix

How could I generate a matrix (a reference to an array of references) X by Y in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`perldoc perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html):

```
my @random = map [ map rand, 1..5 ], 1..10; # Generates a 5x10 matrix of random values
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $x = 5;
my $y = 3;
my $val = 23;

my @matrix = (
  map [ ($val) x $x ], 1 .. $y
);

use Data::Dump;
dd @matrix;
```

Output:

```
(
  [23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
  [23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
  [23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
)
```